# What are some advantages/disadvantages on moving Case Assignment Rule logic to a Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, case, automation, assignment-rules

We have tremendous amount of logic in our Case flows and a ton of Case Assignment rules which work almost every time in tandem. But whenever a new requirement comes in (a very basic one), we spend a lot of time in building the new logic and in regression testing.

I think if we move the assignment logic to a Flow, we have more control over the transaction and fairly easier maintainability on the Flow/overall Case logic.

I know this a very open ended question but would like to hear some feedback from the community on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Flow, but there are tradeoffs. If you can fit your logic in a before save flow, it should perform better than the assignment rule. Note that some paths that may create a case, such as web-to-case, won't have an attached contact or account in the before insert event, so you may need to account for that limitation. For the after insert event, you'll actually cause recursion that you wouldn't with assignment rules, so it would perform worse than just using assignment rules. Either way, you'll also be completely cutting off the various ways in which Salesforce allows you to assign ownership automatically, such as the "Assign case using the active assignment rule" feature in the UI, as well as the AssignmentRuleHeader API feature that allows you to use a default rule or any configured rule. In other words, there is a significant downside to converting assignment rules to a flow, with little to gain. However, if you're in that small set of circumstances where it does make sense, it could offer considerable improvement, despite the limitations.

Comment: As always, thank you for clarifying.